# UItabbar settitlecolor,iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to change the color of the text of tabbar item,programmatically.
I am using

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                                       [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                       [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                       [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                       nil]];
```

Which should works on iOS5 and above.
But my apps gets crashed with error at console :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance setTitleTextAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79f5790'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Not sure, why i am getting a crash.
Also please suggest, if there is any other way to change the font color of the tabbar items.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTitleTextAttributes` is the method of `UIBarItem` class.

so fetch  tab bar items and set their title attributes.

see this

[tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/articles/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-tab-bar-using-ios-5-appearance-api/)

for setting styles in tab bar

Comment: `UIBarItem` are also used in toolbars and tabbars. Changing the appearance will also change the toolbar item. You should be more  specific if you are using the appearance proxy.

Comment: @rckoenes, yap UITabBarItem is also the subclass of UIBarItem thats why it provides setTitleTextAttributes method. now i change the text of my answer 'fetch tab bar items' .

Comment: Thanks for the info, that tutorial is showing ,how to change the appearance, which i already implemented.I am just not able to change the color of text,since by default its white, and my image is light in color, that white is not visible,so i hv to change the color of text only.

Comment: @FirstTimer, one more way is fetch the label for tabBar item and  explicitly change the TextColor of that label.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these answers are correct (at least for iOS 6).

You're missing `forState:` at the end of the call. 
Example

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                       [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                       [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                       nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

The title in not part of the `UITabBar` but `UITabBarItem` thus replace `UITabBar` :

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
```

Comment: But my app crashes when I use this.

Comment: @bagusflyer can you post the code your used and the crash log. If used the method above in my one apps and it does work.